# how to use the function dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath is called by tableView method inside the tableviewcontroller. And if I understand correctly, tableView method is called several times until all the cells are populated. But what I don't know is where do you get the value for the parameter IndexPath? I want to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath for a method that I created because I want to access my cell to copy some values of its properties.

**NOTE:**
I already populated my cell, which means that I successfully used the method tableView.

**(Edit) ADDITIONAL INFO:**
I'm trying to create a profile and edit profile tableviews. Inside the profile tableview, I displayed the name, address, contact#, etc., of the user. Also, I have a segue called edit profile. In the edit profile, I have textfields for each category (name, address, etc.). What I want to do is, if I edit the contents of the textfields, I should be able to display the new contents in my profile tableview. An example case would be: in the profile view I'm displaying -> name:human, address:earth (each in its own cell). Now if I go to editprofile tableview, I will edit the contents such that -> name:alien, address:mars. After that, there is a button called 'apply' to end editing of contents and go back to profile tableview. If I go back to profile view, the display should now be name:alien, address:mars and not name:human, address:earth.

Here is some code if it's any help. The code is called by a button in tableviewcontroller. "MyCell" is the class of my cell. This code is not working properly. I hope someone can help me fix this.

```
- (IBAction)updateCopies:(id)sender {
       static NSString *ident = @"MyCell";
       NSIndexPath *indexPath;
       //create cell
       MyCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident forIndexPath:indexPath];
       //create variable for accessing cells
       int row = [indexPath row];
       _labelValues[row] = cell.textField.text
```

}

Comment: Ah I see now that you don't have a value for indexPath. What are you exactly trying to do? Where is this button?

Comment: Hi Rengers, I'm trying to copy a value of one of the property of MyCell.h (the property that I'm talking about is textField). The button is a property of my tableview. I'm sorry I can't post a snapshot of my storyboard right now because I don't have access to my Mac right now. I'll post it tomorrow if it's going to help.

Comment: Each cell has a button? I would create a delegate for the cell and handle the button taps in the cell itself. Then use a delegate method to 'forward' this to the controller. You can include the text field content in the delegate method as well.

Comment: It looks like I can't post the screenshot since I don't have enough reputation. Anyway, I only have one button. I'll edit my post and try to describe what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I've updated my answer to point you in the direction of a possible solution.

Comment: @user3161828 You have got 4 answers for your question, so you should "accept" one of these answers by clicking on the check mark! (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). - For follow-up problems, please post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You should only use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` when you need to supply the table view with a cell to display. If you want to get the UITableViewCell object at a certain index, you should use [cellForRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:).

**Your problem**

What you really need is a model class. You can then pass this to the edit controller, which changes the properties. Then when you return to the tableView, you can reload it and display the new properties.

What you could also do is create a delegate protocol for your edit profile controller, something like `EditProfileViewControllerDelegate` with something like:

```
protocol EditProfileViewControllerDelegate {
    - (void)editProfileViewController:(EditProfileViewController *)controller didUpdateName:(NSString *)name address:(NSString *)address;
}
```

You can implement this delegate in your table view controller and use it to update the values when the text is changed. However, this quickly becomes unwieldy, I would not recommend it over using a proper model class.

Comment: Attention that **cellForRowAtIndexPath** will return **nill** if the cell is not visible.

Comment: Yes I misunderstood the question, I've commented on the original question for more explanation about the problem.

Comment: I have a side question regarding your answer, cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath will return a UITableViewCell right? That means that it will be incompatible with my MyCell class.

Comment: It returns a UITableViewCell or nil. This works because MyCell is a UITableViewCell. You can cast it using `cell as MyCell` if needed.

Comment: @NunoVinhas you may be right, but cell will never go out of the context. Because when the user selects a cell and goes to the edit profile page, the cell should be visible else he won't end up on Edit Profile screen. Now, when he comes back the cell is still there and he calls updateCopies method as soon he comes back.

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala: Probably. But I still wouldn't bet on it. Always assume the cell *could* be nil. You end up with much more robust code that way.

Comment: @Rengers so when the cell is nil, then you do not need to do anything, because when the user scrolls, the cell would anyway get populated with new values.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
- (IBAction)updateCopies:(id)sender {
 MyCell *parentCell = (MyCell *)sender.superview;

while (![parentCell isKindOfClass:[MyCell class]]) {   // iOS 7 onwards the table cell hierachy has changed.
    parentCell = parentCell.superview;
}

UIView *parentView = parentCell.superview;

while (![parentView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {   // iOS 7 onwards the table cell hierachy has changed.
    parentView = parentView.superview;
}


UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)parentView;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:(MyCell *)parentCell];

NSLog(@"indexPath = %@", indexPath);
}
```

Comment: That works until Apple decides to change the view hierarchy again. (As they did in iOS7).

Answer (score 0):

You can get indexPath using CGPoint..You can use dequeueResusableCell for reusability of the cell..

```
- (IBAction)updateCopies:(id)sender {
  CGPoint position = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero
                                   toView:self.tableView];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:position];
       //create variable for accessing cells
  MyCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       int row = [indexPath row];
 _labelValues[row] = cell.textField.text
}
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Well I got what you want to accomplish.

Firstly, there is a `delegate` which is being called when you click/select a cell and go to the Edit Profile page. That delegate is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    ///
}
```

Make a global variable, say `selectedIndexPath` which holds the current cell index path which is being edited. Update this value each time when you go to edit profile page.

Like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    // code to go to edit page...
}
```

Now in your `updateCopies` Method, do like this

```
- (IBAction)updateCopies:(id)sender {

       //get the existing cell with the indexPath
       [self.tableView beginUpdates];
       [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedIndexPath]];
       [self.tableView endUpdates];

     //rest of your code goes here...
}
```